# iOS TTS error: couldn't set footprint on TTS instance

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

When using iOS speech to text, I'm getting the following error message in the iOS log. It still speaks fine, so I am not sure if it is important, but it doesn't sound good. Any clues what this is about? Can't find anything on the internet.

```
 TTSSpeechBundle)[1506] <Notice>: Speech: Error (hex)80000011
 (int)-2147483631 at
 /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/TextToSpeech/TextToSpeech-235.0.4/NashvilleBundle/TTSVocalizer.m:1098
 (couldn't set footprint on TTS instance)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ignore it. It's about Apple's code, not yours, and your functionality isn't being affected.

If you're feeling restless, you could file a bug with Apple, chiefly because the framework shouldn't be dumping these messages into your console (where they crowd out your own log messages). They do this a lot, and it's really annoying.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sounds sensible!